# Проблема с типом данных?

Tags: javascript

```
var time = {
  hours: 10,
  minutes: this.hours * 60
}
time.minutes
```

Выводит NaN, почему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что в данном случае `this` - это глобальный объект и у него нет свойства `hours` - следовательно *this.hours* вернет *undefined* и при умножении даст *NaN*.

Варианты решения зависят от конечной задачи.

1. Единовременная инициализация

   ```
   var time = {
     hours: 10,
     minutes: 10 * 60
   }
   time.minutes
   ```
2. использование функции

   ```
   var time = {
     hours: 10,
     minutes: function minutes(){ return this.hours * 60; }
   }
   time.minutes();
   ```
3. использование геттера

   ```
   var time = {
     hours: 10,
     get minutes(){ return this.hours * 60; }
   }
   time.minutes;
   ```
4. использование функции конструктора

   ```
   function Times(){
       this.hours = 10;
       this.minutes = this.hours * 60;
   }

   new Times().minutes;
   ```

Comment: во втором случае именованная фунция обязательна?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, нет, это функциональное выражение, в нем имя - опционально.